# EXcel images linked to Cell Value (VBA)

Tags: excel, image, vba, cell

I'm trying to display images in Excel worksheet that are linked to Cell values

example - if Cell A1 = value 10 then display image (picture 10)

and then for another cell

If Cell Cell A10 - value 90% then display image (picture 90).

I have used the below VBA code and it worked fine for A1 but then when I added in the 2nd Cell value and picture it would only display the A1 value/picture.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("J27")) Is Nothing _
    And Not Target.Count > 1 Then

        For Each shp In Me.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
                shp.Visible = msoFalse

            End If
        Next

        Select Case Range("J27").value
            Case "10"
            Me.Shapes("Picture 10").Visible = msoTrue
            Case "11"
            Me.Shapes("Picture 11").Visible = msoTrue
            Case "12"
            Me.Shapes("Picture 12").Visible = msoTrue
            Case "13"
            Me.Shapes("Picture 13").Visible = msoTrue
            Case "14"
            Me.Shapes("Picture 14").Visible = msoTrue

       End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Please help!

Comment: Please correct the formatting of your code, it will be simpler to detect the problem

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two problems.

- You only have 1 copy of each picture, so if two cells have the same value then they will need to share the same image
- Your code always hides all the images before displaying one of them (so you can never have two displayed at the same time)

I would suggest having all the images hidden, copying them as required and renaming them (to `ImageCellA1` for instance) so that you can reference them by name when you need to delete /update them.

Comment: The above VBA code works when using just  1 Cell value  and multiple images but like the above comment  when I try to add more images linked to another cell value it hides all other images.. I need an AND code or something?

Comment: Like I said, your code hides all images before displaying one of them. That's why you can only see one image, because that's what your code does.